# Symbol font is rasterized when printing from .NET application

Tags: c#, windows, printing, fonts

I am creating a Postscript file from C# by printing to a Postscript printer set up to print to a file. I'm using the .NET PrintDocument class and Graphics.DrawString to render the text.

If I use a symbol or pictograph font such as Symbol or WingDings, the text is rasterized in the Postscript file. If I use e.g. Arial, then the text is not rasterized. My aim is to produce a Postscript file from my application where text using a symbol font is not rasterized.

If I print the same text using symbol font from e.g. notepad the text is not rasterized, so it doesn't at first glance appear to be a printer driver limitation.

What am I doing wrong/different that's causing the rasterization?

- The printer's font substitution table is set to not substitute the font.
- Symbol font is available on the printers I have tried.
- Choosing another Postscript printer driver makes no difference.
- Using the TextRenderer.DrawText produces the same result.
- Printing using the Symbol font from other applications (Notepad, Word, etc) does *not* result in rasterized output.

```
#region Usings

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

#endregion

public class PrintingExample
{
    private string _fontName;
    private string _printerName;
    private string _textToPrint;

    //private bool endPrintFired = false;

    // private bool keepGoing = true;
    private Font printFont;

    public PrintingExample(string fontName, string printerName, string textToPrint)
    {
        _fontName = fontName;
        _printerName = printerName;
        _textToPrint = textToPrint;
    }

    // The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed.
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        const float fontSize = 14.0f;

        var fFamily = new FontFamily(_fontName);
        printFont = new Font(fFamily, fontSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);


        var leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        var topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(_textToPrint, printFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(leftMargin, topMargin), new StringFormat());

        // Only printing one page
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }

    // Print the file.
    public void Printing()
    {
        try
        {
            var outputFile = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                outputFile = Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\print\", Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".ps");

                var pd = new PrintDocument {PrinterSettings = {
                    PrinterName = _printerName, 
                    PrintToFile = true,
                    PrintFileName = outputFile}

                };
                pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;


                PrintController pc = new StandardPrintController();
                PrintController printController = new PrintControllerWithStatusDialog(pc);

                pd.PrintController = printController;

                // Print the document.
                pd.Print();
            }
            finally
            {
                // For debugging, loads in default associated application
                if (File.Exists(outputFile))
                    Process.Start(outputFile);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    // This is the main entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string fontName = "Symbol";
        const string printerName = "<Choose an installed Postscript printer here>";

        const string textToPrint = "1234567890\r\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var p = new PrintingExample(fontName, printerName, textToPrint);
        p.Printing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Windows 2012R2, 10, Server 2016, and Server 2019 (server 2008R2 was unaffected, which led us to open an MS case). Only some fonts were affected. It was resolved in the March 2021 OS updates for Windows 10, Server 2016 and Server 2019